# Pandas dataframe outputing wrong calculations

Tags: python, pandas

This is the daily returns of a stock, I have the data stored in a dataframe called simple_return.

```
15.3238
15.2006
15.1595
15.1184
15.0773
```

I execute the following code:

```
simple_return = simple_return/simple_return.shift(1) - 1
```

when I do so I get the following output:

```
1
nan
-0.3419843641916497
-0.9511866154929438
20.205810646078827
-0.2978778443113772
-0.06755908520277276
```

The following output is false since I did the calculation on Libreoffice Calc, the correct calculations are:

```
15.3238 
15.2006 -0.008039781255302
15.1595 -0.00270384063787
15.1184 -0.002711171212771
15.0773 -0.002718541644618
```

Why is the code making wrong calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `pct_change`

```
df.price.pct_change()
Out[234]: 
0        nan
1   -0.00804
2   -0.00270
3   -0.00271
4   -0.00272
Name: price, dtype: float64
```